# Why is the pressure low in the top sprayer of my Bosch dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

Bosch Dishwasher SHU43C02UC/17

I noticed that the filter screen was raised at the far left corner.  So took it the rest of the way off and cleaned out round filter as long as I was in there.

Then replaced and fastened filter and screen.

Later when I ran the dishwasher I could hear a noise while it was running.   Dishes came out clean.   But when I ran later, I had very low  pressure.   Some pressure out the bottom spouts but nothing out of the top.

I still hear humming sound when running but much lower.

Dishwasher pumps out water fine...just no washing pressure.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: You probably dislodged some material that now resides in the upper sprayer plumbing. You'll have to clean that out.

Comment: That crossed my mind, but the lower sprayer pressure is not enough to even make it spin.  I took the sprayer off and ran a cycle with the door open.   Pressure coming from pump is very low.   But at end of cycle water exits adequately.

Comment: Mr D it looks like you answered your question, chech the pump possibly replace or clean the food particles out of the intake.

Comment: So as I think about the whole situation.   The filter screen was raised due to a small rib bone that somehow got underneath its edge.   So I am thinking that there must have been a piece of cartiledge or bone that was under it and therefore released and would have made it by the catch filter since it was out while I adjusted the tray.   With that in mind and the resulting change in the function of the dishwasher...would you say that I damaged the impellor? or circulation pump or could it just be stuck in there and I might fix it by taking apart and cleaning out?

Comment: Or, based on events, is it probably broken?   Trying to avoid needless labor.  May just go get a new one.